# Twitter Popular Tags On Apache Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I am new to apache spark. I was trying to run https://github.com/prabeesh/SparkTwitterAnalysis/tree/0.2.0 example but console is giving me the following error:

```
 WARN scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl: Initial job has not accepted any resources; check your cluster UI to ensure that workers are registered and have sufficient memory
```

I have started the server using `nc -lk 9999` and I have compiled the code by sbt/sbt package
and have excecuted the code using `sbt`/ `sbt 'run spark://localhost:9999 <keys as specifies> hashtag'`

What is the reason for this error and how to resolve it

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the message, either your workers are not registered with the cluster or they do not have enough memory to run your task. Go to cluster UI page from your browser and make sure your worker nodes are configured correctly. If the nodes are working, then try to increase their available memory.

Comment: Hey anas thanks for responding. I have checked them and allocated them nodes memory upto 5GB. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25975250/apache-spark-streaming-data-initial-job-has-not-accepted-any-resources I have explained in details about my problem

Comment: I think your cluster is not working properly. Have you restarted your cluster?

Comment: Can you please share code where you are initializing the spark context.